# Twitter Bootstrap Navbar: How to create two separate rows?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am using Twitter bootstrap to create my fixed navbar up top, and I wanted to mimic something like [Kickstarter's](http://www.kickstarter.com/) navbar, where they create a new line in between 'Discover' and 'great projects.' I've tried using an escape "\n" as well as "< br />" (i realize there's a space in front of br)  to create a new line, but it messes up the format of the rest of the navbar, and pushes the logo up. What would be the correct way to create 2 lines, but maintaining the overall height of the navbar?

Answer (score 1):

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="#">
      <span class="li-head">Discover</span>
      <span class="li-tail">great projects</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

.nav li a > span { display:block; }
```

Comment: Thank you Calvin! The only problem with this is that when I hover over Discover, it only highlights discover and not 'great projects.' what would be the best way to combine them? I tried making an id name for <li>, but that changed the positions of the other links in the navbar, and made everything look off

Comment: How are you handling the hover? By right hovering over either "Discover" or "great projects" would be hovering over the same <a> tag

Comment: I am using Twitter bootstrap's Less variables like this: 
@\navbarLinkColor: @\white;
@\navbarLinkColorHover: @\orange;. However, the white or orange doesn't apply to your code, so I had to retype that. Is there a way I can get your link connected to @\navbarLinkColor?